# How to select row if my column values in comma in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table name myTable with rows like below:

```
*--------------------------------------------*
| S.No. | user_id  | Event Name | Event Date |
*--------------------------------------------*
|  101  |  9,19    | Juniorun   | 25-June-19 |
*--------------------------------------------*
|  102  |  9,20    | Juniorun1  | 30-June-19 |
*--------------------------------------------*
|  103  |  9,21    | Juniorun2  | 27-June-19 |
*--------------------------------------------*
|  104  |  9,18,19 | Juniorun3  | 26-June-19 |
*--------------------------------------------*
```

Now I have user id 19 And through this, I want to select row whose user Id is 19.

I want:

```
*--------------------------------------------*
| S.No. | user_id  | Event Name | Event Date |
*--------------------------------------------*
|  101  |  9,19    | Juniorun   | 25-June-19 |
*--------------------------------------------*
|  104  |  9,18,19 | Juniorun3  | 26-June-19 |
*--------------------------------------------*
```

For this I am using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE user_id IN ('19');
```

But my query is not given any value. It is showing blank.

Comment: Better to normalize your database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php), you can achieve the expected result:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('19', user_id);
```

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fb1e6cabfe5202d98d01f7500e628292)

Comment: Perfectly working, I am not using > 0 I do not need this. Thanks buddy

Comment: @SantoshKhatri You're Welcome. Yes `> 0` is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Given that user_id is stored as a String, you can use the `LIKE` operator (wouldn't recommend)

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE user_id LIKE '%19%';
```

or, use `FIND_IN_SET` in the WHERE clause as,

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('19', user_id) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

try FIND_IN_SET

SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE FIND_IN_SET(19,user_id)

Answer (score 0):

The FIND_IN_SET() function returns the position of a string within a list of strings.
FIND_IN_SET(string, string_list)
Parameter   Description
string  Required. The string to search for
string_list     Required. The list of string values to be searched (separated by commas)
Then your SQL will be

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE FIND_IN_SET(19,user_id)
```